# zeppelin with sparkr is not displaying dataframe as table

Tags: sparkr, apache-zeppelin

The zeppelin R interpreter documentation states:

```
If you return a data.frame, Zeppelin will attempt to display it using Zeppelin's built-in visualizations.
```

This can be seen in the documentation example:

[image]

However, when I attempt to run the same R commands from my zeppelin 0.6.0 notebook, I see the following:

[image]

Any idea why I'm not seeing the tabular output?

Comment: I have the same problem? Any idea?

Comment: Same problem, any updates on this?

Comment: Possible way is to register data frame as temp table `registerTempTable(dataframe, "temp_table")` and use sql interpreter to display `%sql select * from temp_table`

Comment: Do you have tried to use `z.show(varname)` in order to map the dataframe from the interpreter to this inbuilt plot function. Al least that's the way to do within the python interpreter: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/interpreter/python.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a temp table and then do a `select * from temp_table`, just as @Arun Gunalan suggested.